# Accessing Sharepoint webservices from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

In one of my application I need to use **Microsoft Share-point Server**.

But I cannot successfully authenticate through web-services.

I use [_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx](http:///_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx) for login but I got "PasswordNotMatch" or 403 :Forbidden error.

I got Authentication Mode as "Forms". Any help?

One More Question is:

After a sucessfull login, how can I handle further request -getList/addList? Any additional processing needed?